# how to display a messagebox with hyperlink use pywin32 and python?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pywin32

My code like this:

```
import win32api
info = 'Starting sucess. To http://highwe.net/hostList get more information!'
win32api.MessageBox(None,info,"Hold your Host",win32con.MB_OK|win32con.MB_ICONQUESTION)
```

and it will display a MessageBox with the info,but what I want is the href can be a hyperlink which user could click.

Note:the win32api seems no  DialogBox inside.

What should I do?